# Split an html document into multiple documents on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I want to submit html into a text area and then on submit I want it to read the file, find the class selector and break down the html into multiple html files and save them in a directory.

Any ideas on how this could be achieved?

For example let say that I submit this into a textarea and I hit submit :

```
<table class="yoda">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="yoda">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On submit I want to grab each yoda and save it  in a new html file in a directory.

Thank you all in advance.
I am not sure if I need to Use php to achieve this or if I need to use javascript.

Comment: FYI/sidenote: ID's must be unique. Use `class` instead if you want to use the same for X-reason or use different ID names.

Comment: Thank you Fred I have amended my question.

Comment: +1 for yoda, that is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

1. Submit the HTML normally via submit to PHP and use something like
   [SimpleDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library or PHP native DOM/XML methods to parse and
   save it as individual snippets (**best method**)
2. Parse the HTML on the client (using
   jquery or native ) and submit it as JSON to PHP (remember to escape
   HTML strings). Process JSON using PHP on the server and save the
   snippets.

Comment: Your first point seems exactly like what I need. Thank you very much. I will give it a try and see how it goes. Thank you Michal

Answer (score 0):

textarea inside of parsed document (HTML document).

submit anything in use of an object inside of parsed document is possible.

but split of submitted data ... use server software like php.

Javascript works on client.